# Volume rocker doesn't change volume when using speakers - Lenovo X1 Carbon 7th Gen

Tags: audio, release-hera, lenovo

I installed elementary OS 5.1 Hera on my Lenovo X1 Carbon 7th Gen, but the volume rocker doesn't work when playing audio on the speakers. I can put it on maximum or minimum but there is no change in the actual volume. The only thing that works is muting.

Curiously this only happens when playing audio on the speakers. When I use headphones or Bluetooth speakers it works fine. Any idea on what's causing the issue or how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the instructions here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_(Gen_7)#Audio

Comment: Thank you! That worked